# Why cannot a feature be finished with unstaged changes?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree, git-flow

Is there a special reason why I cannot "finish a feature" (using git-flow) while my sandbox contains unstaged/non-commited changes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Git cannot merge while you have non-committed changes.

You can do the following:

- `git stash` to store your changes temporarily
- finish your feature
- `git stash pop` to get the stashed changes back on top of your current working directory

Comment: I wonder as to what prevented this answer from also including an actual ANSWER to the question, which was a "why does it do it" and not a "how can I get around it" as getting around should be fairly clear as the commit message tells you exactly what to do...